# How to force IIS to/inform IIS that it should spin up more worker processes?

Tags: iis, service-workers

Our system generally processes in two services which are run under IIS. Service A gets HTTP requests, parses the content, and shoots it to RabbitMQ. Service B takes messages from RabbitMQ, parses them further, and writes them to a database.

IIS can detect when it should spin up more worker processes for Service A, because it gets HTTP requests. However, because Service B takes messages from RabbitMQ, it doesn't know when to spin up more processes, and thus it's stuck at 1/20 processes.

How can I fix that? I don't even know what vocabulary I should use to research that.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly. You should not use IIS to run non websites, make a windows service instead.

Secondly. You *probably* don't want more than one thread in service B. (well ok more than number of cores threads)

Presumably the reason you are off loading it to a worker process is because its CPU bound? Therefore you want to use all the processing power available on the machine to finish the first job before you start the second.

Theres no point in working on more than one at a time on a single computer.

To scale up you need to put a second copy of service B on a second computer. Now you have two machines working on the task list and can add as many more as you can afford.

Comment: It's not CPU bound. It's work that cannot be done because the database is too slow. It's just a bunch of time wasted.

Comment: oh well its cpu bound by the db then. no point firing off more requests than the db can handle

Comment: the goal of processing more requests than the DB can handle is that I can process the messages into the format the DB expects, and store them within the service's local DB safely if the connection to the remote get severed, and to keep data flowing through the application